# How to convert two or more rows into columns in Oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a table mapping that has Column names and values as shown below. **(I have more than 20 columns)**.

[Original Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sejvi.png)

I want to convert this into:

**(0/NULL)**
[Final Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eK9wh.png)

Can anyone please help here.

I have written the below query which worked for only one column but how to do it for more than two-columns?

select * from cte3 
 pivot(
 min(1) for column1 in ( a , b , c , d )
 )
  order by id

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the **conditional aggregation** as it can not be handled by `PIVOT`.

```
SQL> WITH CTE(ID,COLUMN1,COLUMN2,COLUMN3,COLUMN4) AS
  2  (SELECT 1,'A','E','I','M' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  3  SELECT 2,'B','F','J','N' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  4  SELECT 3,'C','G','K','O' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  5  SELECT 4,'D','H','L','P' FROM DUAL)
  6  --your query starts from here
  7  SELECT ID,
  8         COALESCE(SUM(CASE WHEN 'A' IN (COLUMN1,COLUMN2,COLUMN3,COLUMN4) THEN 1 END),0) AS A,
  9         COALESCE(SUM(CASE WHEN 'B' IN (COLUMN1,COLUMN2,COLUMN3,COLUMN4) THEN 1 END),0) AS B,
 10         COALESCE(SUM(CASE WHEN 'C' IN (COLUMN1,COLUMN2,COLUMN3,COLUMN4) THEN 1 END),0) AS C,
 11         COALESCE(SUM(CASE WHEN 'D' IN (COLUMN1,COLUMN2,COLUMN3,COLUMN4) THEN 1 END),0) AS D,
 12         COALESCE(SUM(CASE WHEN 'E' IN (COLUMN1,COLUMN2,COLUMN3,COLUMN4) THEN 1 END),0) AS E,
 13         COALESCE(SUM(CASE WHEN 'F' IN (COLUMN1,COLUMN2,COLUMN3,COLUMN4) THEN 1 END),0) AS F,
 14         COALESCE(SUM(CASE WHEN 'G' IN (COLUMN1,COLUMN2,COLUMN3,COLUMN4) THEN 1 END),0) AS G,
 15         COALESCE(SUM(CASE WHEN 'H' IN (COLUMN1,COLUMN2,COLUMN3,COLUMN4) THEN 1 END),0) AS H,
 16         COALESCE(SUM(CASE WHEN 'I' IN (COLUMN1,COLUMN2,COLUMN3,COLUMN4) THEN 1 END),0) AS I,
 17         COALESCE(SUM(CASE WHEN 'J' IN (COLUMN1,COLUMN2,COLUMN3,COLUMN4) THEN 1 END),0) AS J,
 18         COALESCE(SUM(CASE WHEN 'K' IN (COLUMN1,COLUMN2,COLUMN3,COLUMN4) THEN 1 END),0) AS K,
 19         COALESCE(SUM(CASE WHEN 'L' IN (COLUMN1,COLUMN2,COLUMN3,COLUMN4) THEN 1 END),0) AS L,
 20         COALESCE(SUM(CASE WHEN 'M' IN (COLUMN1,COLUMN2,COLUMN3,COLUMN4) THEN 1 END),0) AS M,
 21         COALESCE(SUM(CASE WHEN 'N' IN (COLUMN1,COLUMN2,COLUMN3,COLUMN4) THEN 1 END),0) AS N,
 22         COALESCE(SUM(CASE WHEN 'O' IN (COLUMN1,COLUMN2,COLUMN3,COLUMN4) THEN 1 END),0) AS O,
 23         COALESCE(SUM(CASE WHEN 'P' IN (COLUMN1,COLUMN2,COLUMN3,COLUMN4) THEN 1 END),0) AS P
 24    FROM CTE
 25  GROUP BY ID;

        ID  A  B  C  D  E  F  G  H  I  J  K  L  M  N  O  P
---------- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
         1  1  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  1  0  0  0
         2  0  1  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  1  0  0
         4  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  1
         3  0  0  1  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  1  0

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
with q1 as (
select 1 id, 'A' column1, 'E' column2, 'I' column3, 'M' column4 from dual
union all
select 2 id, 'B' column1, 'F' column2, 'J' column3, 'N' column4 from dual
union all
select 3 id, 'C' column1, 'G' column2, 'K' column3, 'O' column4 from dual
union all
select 4 id, 'D' column1, 'H' column2, 'L' column3, 'P' column4 from dual
),
--select * from q1;
q2 as (
select 
   id,
   column1 as c1, case when column1 in ('A','B','C','D') then id end as c1p,
   column2 as c2, case when column2 in ('E','F','G','H') then 4+id end as c2p,
   column3 as c3, case when column3 in ('I','J','K','L') then 8+id end as c3p,
   column4 as c4, case when column4 in ('M','N','O','P') then 12+id end as c4p
from q1
order by 1
),
--select * from q2;
q3 as (
select id, c1p as pos, c1 as val from q2
union all
select id, c2p as pos, c2 as val from q2
union all
select id, c3p as pos, c3 as val from q2
union all
select id, c4p as pos, c4 as val from q2
order by 1,2
),
--select * from q3;
q4 as (
select distinct pos, val from q3 order by 1
),
--select * from q4;
q5 as (
select q3.id, q4.pos, q4.val, case when q3.val = q4.val then 1 else 0 end as nval
from q3 
partition by (q3.id)
right outer join q4
on (q3.pos = q4.pos)
order by 1,2
)
--select * from q5;
select 
   id, 
   sum(A) as A, sum(B) as B, sum(C) as C, sum(D) as D,
   sum(E) as E, sum(F) as F, sum(G) as G, sum(H) as H,
   sum(I) as I, sum(J) as J, sum(K) as K, sum(L) as L,
   sum(M) as M, sum(N) as N, sum(O) as O, sum(P) as P
from q5
pivot ( sum(nval) for val in (   
           'A' as A,'B' as B,'C' as C,'D' as D,
           'E' as E,'F' as F,'G' as G,'H' as H,
           'I' as I,'J' as J,'K' as K,'L' as L,
           'M' as M,'N' as N,'O' as O,'P' as P
        )
)
group by id
order by 1
;
```

[Snapshot of Results as expected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3k9VO.jpg)

Comment: I cannot hard code the values because I have almost 500 - 600 different ID`s every month and different values. All the IDs are unique.

Comment: What's the hardcoding... A,B,C, ... and 'A', 'B', 'C', ... how does the other answer avoid hardcoding? Even that one uses the literals ... some alternate syntax may be possible but difficult to give the answer you need w/o knowing more.